# Javascript: To remove duplicate values having same key from an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects in which one key:value pair contains duplicate values.so I would like to remove the replicated values in the object.

For example,I want to trim the duplicate values from `mapDataWithDuplicate` which is shown below,

```
mapDataWithDuplicate=[
    {
      lat: "39.562686920166", 
      lng: "-105.106826782227",  
      storeId: "0839", 
      stopId: "12,1,12,23,23"
    },
    {
      lat: "39.6455154418945", 
      lng: "-105.339477539063", 
      storeId: "0010", 
      stopId: "24,2,13,24,13,2,13,24,24"
    }
]
```

I want to remove duplicate value from stopId and sort it in the ascending order. Any help would be appreciated.

The result should look like this -

```
mapDataWithDuplicate=[
        {
          lat: "39.562686920166", 
          lng: "-105.106826782227",  
          storeId: "0839", 
          stopId: "1,12,23"
        },
        {
          lat: "39.6455154418945", 
          lng: "-105.339477539063", 
          storeId: "0010", 
          stopId: "2,13,24"
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Hey there, would you mind showing us what you tried out so far? Would be great to help you get this sorted out yourself rather than providing you with an answer - thats not quite what stackoverflow is for.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.map` to iterate each item and convert `stopId` into `Set` which will remove duplicate values and return final result.

```js
const mapDataWithDuplicate = [
  {
    lat: "39.562686920166",
    lng: "-105.106826782227",
    storeId: "0839",
    stopId: "12,1,12,23,23"
  },
  {
    lat: "39.6455154418945",
    lng: "-105.339477539063",
    storeId: "0010",
    stopId: "24,2,13,24,13,2,13,24,24"
  }
]

const processData = (list) => {
  return list.map(data => {
    const set = new Set(data.stopId.split(","));
    const ids = [...set].sort((num1, num2) => num1 - num2);
    const stopId = ids.join(",");
    return { ...data, stopId };
  });
}

console.log(processData(mapDataWithDuplicate));
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't mind using a library, this is the most efficient way to do both it

```
var _ = require('lodash');

mapDataWithDuplicate.forEach(e => {
  const convertToArray = _.map(_.words(e.stopId), _.parseInt)
  console.log(_.uniq(_.sortBy(convertToArray)));
})
```

I have to convert the string into an array first before execute. It would be better if your data is an integer already so converting wouldn't be necessary.

There's a function that does both but somehow I can't use it maybe you could try it
Here's the documentation:
https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#sortedUniq